# In Cakephp how to retain Edit id when re-posting the url with a language parameter

Tags: php, url, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a multilingual website with English and Arabic support.

The URL of a generated edit page has the form:

`eng/advertisements/edit/20`

I use this html helper link to change the language:

`$this->Html->link('English', array('language'=>'eng')`

Now the problem is that when I change the language for the edit page using the above mentioned helper my language does get changed but the id is lost.

The generated URL is:

`eng/advertisements/edit/`

Because of this I get errors on the page, because the page gets loaded without an id.

How i can retain the id value when using the helper link method to change the language?
The helper link is working fine for all the links where there is no requirement of id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Html->link('English', array_merge($this->params['pass'], array('language' => 'eng')));
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you very much. Can u tell me shortly what this $this->params['pass'] command is exactly doing here. Visually it seems that one is merging parameter 'pass'.

Comment: @Fraz `$this->params` contains all the parameters for this request, like controller name, action, named parameters etc. Try `debug($this->params)`. `params['pass']` contains the unnamed parameters, so `42` for a URL like `array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar', 42)`. In the code above I'm just merging all those extra parameters into the link so they're retained in the generated link.